# External Javascript is not working in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I am creating a react app using `create-react-app`. I have some external javascript libraries for template design in main `index.html`

```
 <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/common_scripts.js"></script>
 <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/main.js"></script>
 <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

These JS files are working on first page when the application gets started. But these libraries are not working when redirect to other page from first page.
From what I understand, these files are rendering but their `functions, variables, and methods` are not accessible when the route is changed. 
I am using `react-router-dom v4` for routing .

I googled it and found a solution- 
To render the JS libraries by `ComponentDidMount()` method

```
ComponentDidMount(){
    loadjs('./js/main.js', function(){
    loadjs('./js/common_scripts.js)
    });
  }
```

But even this solution is not working.
Please help to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same problem did you get any solution ?

Comment: I used `window` object to use jquery functions and events   `import $ from 'jquery';` in main `index.js` and then access any jquery events like `componentDidUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
      window.$('.hero_single').addClass('start_bg_zoom');
    }`

Comment: thank you for the reply but I am new to front end development so I didn't get what you said, I have multiple external js file like in your case like jquery, bootstrap,  owl.carousel, nice select, and a custom main.js which includes all initialization etc How can I make all page work fine

Comment: @AzadHussain can you find the fix.. i am facing the same issue

Comment: Refer to the below posted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76165168/8101966

Answer (score 1):

This is how i import Jquery into my create react app

**Jquery:**

1. first run `npm install jquery`
2. `index.js`

`import * as $ from 'jquery'`

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = $
```

see: http://blog.oddicles.org/create-react-app-importing-bootstrap-jquery-cleanly-node-js/

Alternativly you can attach the scripts to a window object and then call them as needed:

Try following steps:

including the external js file link in your /public/index.html
use the external library with prefix window.
for example, JQuery.

put following line in your /public/index.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
```

use it in your project:

```
window.$("#btn1").click(function(){
    alert("Text: " + $("#test").text());
});
```

`

See this for more details:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3007

Comment: `window.jQuery = window.$ = $` did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

You are using `componentWillMount()` instead of `componentDidMount()`.

I think that is the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You can set that js files on window object and then you can access it by window.your_name to object..

You have to set that in index file

Answer (score 0):

Try using `import()` inside `componentDidMount()`

The import() is self explaining.It just import's the JavaScript files.

```
import('your_URL')
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but its giving error of vriables like  `Line 3:  'WOW' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 3:  'Switchery' is not defined    no-undef
  Line 3:  Unexpected use of 'location'  no-restricted-globals
  Line 3:  Unexpected use of 'location'  no-restricted-globals`

Comment: looks like you are trying to import a JQuery minified version file. Use Jquery from NPM [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery)

Comment: I am using jQuery from NPM for Ajax request.

Comment: So avoid importing jquery. try dynamically importing the rest of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call event using window object. reference `<a href="https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3007#issuecomment-357863643">Link</a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
const loadScript = (src) => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = src
    script.addEventListener('load', function () {
      resolve()
    })
    script.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
      reject(e)
    })
    document.body.appendChild(script)
    document.body.removeChild(script)
  })
}

 useEffect(() => {
    loadScript(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/js/plugin.min.js`)
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setLoading(false)
      }, 500)
      loadScript(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/js/main.js`)
    }, 200)
  }, [])
```