# Javascript file is not working as intended in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, create-react-app, html-templates

I am creating a website using a template of https://bootstrapmade.com/arsha-free-bootstrap-html-template-corporate/ and using react to render it but it is not rendering properly like loading spinner is keep spinning, swipers are not working and those functionalities are related to javascript files. I also have included it correctly in reacts index.html fileg perfect because included css file is running. It is running perfectly without react so please help me solve this issue.Please again...

I have tried both relative path and absolute path linking[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH9ir.png)

```
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendor/aos/aos.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendor/glightbox/js/glightbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendor/waypoints/noframework.waypoints.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js"></script>

<!-- Template Main JS File -->
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you setup the react project from scratch, or did you use any tools like ```create-react-app```, If you are kinda new to react i suggest you to use the npm package ```create-react-app`` to have a better boiler plate code, Also there are some other react boiler-plate generators also

Comment: Yes I used create-react-app

Comment: Then it should be fine tho, Is it working in dev server mode ie : with ```npm start```

Comment: Yes @SARANSURYA I used create-react-app and it also is running on browser but the loading spinner keeps spinning, it does not happen when i run it without react just using html file in template package.

Comment: Can you post the code that you are running atleast, a minimum working example in react-sandbox ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered that issue today, even came here to recognize the answer but find none.

I managed to recognize the issue which seems to be specific, not a general solution.

My js scripts were written like below:

```
$('.scroll-top').on('click', function () {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 75);
  });
```

So, I re-wrote the event like below:

```
$(document).on("click", ".scroll-top", function () {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 75);
  });
```

That should work. What I recognized is that those imported scripts are not running in order because of the kind of scripts in them. So, you have to access the events from the document object.

Let me know if that solves your issue.

Comment: The question referred to a problem with React, so your answer, which focuses on jQuery seems not to address it.

Comment: @LajosArpad, even though he's in React, the issue is coming from those imported scripts. He should change them to fit in his codebase. That was my experience which worked.

Comment: He wants to integrate the script into React, so, if we do not focus on React-based solutions, it's always possible that there are further problems with the integration that we ignore. Hence, I advise you to test your idea in React and edit, adding the results.

Comment: Maybe we should view his main.js scripts and could decide what to do. because it's depending on that file. maybe if you have a solution in react js specifically, you should provide it and see.

Comment: No, I did not delve into this question. I have reviewed a few questions and I noticed that you have provided a non-React answer to a React question.